# Errors wihen buildng NetCDF: 'cd: IR/grib2/lib: No such file or directory'

Tags: gcc, makefile, gfortran, netcdf, csh

I tried to installing netcdf-4.1.3. After configuring the netcdf-4.1.3 file, i had errors with my 'make' command. The error message is below

```
ameyaw_prince@Mytoses-ThinkPad-T430:~/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3$ make
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/include'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/include'
Making all in libdispatch
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/libdispatch'
/bin/bash ../libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link /usr/bin/gcc  -g -O2  -LIR/grib2/lib -o libdispatch.la  libdispatch_la-parallel.lo libdispatch_la-copy.lo libdispatch_la-file.lo libdispatch_la-dim.lo libdispatch_la-att.lo libdispatch_la-error.lo libdispatch_la-var.lo libdispatch_la-dispatch.lo libdispatch_la-nc_uri.lo libdispatch_la-nclist.lo libdispatch_la-ncbytes.lo libdispatch_la-nchashmap.lo libdispatch_la-nclog.lo   -lm -lcurl 
../libtool: line 5992: cd: IR/grib2/lib: No such file or directory
libtool: link: cannot determine absolute directory name of `IR/grib2/lib'
make[2]: *** [Makefile:328: libdispatch.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3/libdispatch'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:551: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ameyaw_prince/Build_WRF/LIBRARIES/netcdf-4.1.3'
make: *** [Makefile:422: all] Error 2
```

Comment: Hi Mytoses, welcome to Stack Overflow :) I'm afraid we're going to need a lot more information than this in order to help. What is the Makefile you are trying to run? (Ideally a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) rather than the whole thing). Also, could you format your error message as code, so that it's a little easier to read?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read [ask].